# Order by vertex property and edge property if it exists

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, amazon-neptune

Consider a social media site where a `user` (vertex) can `share` (edge) the `post` (vertex) of another `user`.

When you construct the users feed, it would look something like this:

```
const myUserId = 123;

g.V(myUserId)
  .as("myUser")
  .union(
    // posts of users the requesting user follows
    __.out("follow").out("post"),
    // posts shared by users the requesting user follows
    __.out("follow").out("share"),
    // posts of the requesting user
    __.out("post")
  )
```

So far so good, but I need to sort these posts with the following logic:

- If the post has an incoming `share` edge from a user I `follow`, sort by the `createdDate` property of that `share` edge (sort by when the post was shared, not the date the post was created).
- Otherwise, sort by the `createdDate` property of the `post`.

Something like:

```
.order()
.by(
  __.inE("share")
  .as("shareEdge")
  .outV()
  .in_("follow")
  .hasId(myUserId)
  .select("shareEdge")
  .properties("createdDate"),
  order.decr
    )
.by("createdDate", order.decr)
```

The problem is that not all posts have a `share` edge, so this throws an error.

> Error: GraphQL error: Error: Error: Server error:
>   {"requestId":"53e7e66c-302e-4521-ac39-b672b4cb52e6","code":"InvalidParameterException","detailedMessage":"The
>   provided traverser does not map to a value:
>   v[c9b66e21-f8fc-48e5-bdcd-c580248b3f52]->[VertexStep(IN,[share],edge)@[shareEdge],
>   EdgeVertexStep(OUT), VertexStep(IN,[follow],vertex),
>   NeptuneHasStep([~id.eq(f70a5a2d-f606-44b8-8fa6-1e359033223e)]),
>   SelectOneStep(last,shareEdge), NoOpBarrierStep(2500),
>   PropertiesStep([createdDate],property)]"} (499)

How can I sort by an edge property only if the edge exists, and fall back to a vertex property sort where it doesn't?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you can solve this with `coalesce()`. Here's a small sample graph (when asking questions about Gremlin it is always best to include some sample data as a Gremlin script):

```
g.addV('post').property('createdDate',1).as('p1').
  addV('post').property('createdDate',2).as('p2').
  addV('user').as('u1').
  addE('share').to('p2').property('createdDate',0)
```

First the basic ordering using the vertex `createdDate`:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('post').
......1>   order().
......2>     by('createdDate').
......3>   valueMap(true)
==>[id:0,label:post,createdDate:[1]]
==>[id:2,label:post,createdDate:[2]]
```

Then, using `coalesce()` in the `order()` to include the logic you described:

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('post').
......1>   order().
......2>     by(coalesce(inE('share').values('createdDate'),
......3>                 values('createdDate'))).
......4>   valueMap(true) 
==>[id:2,label:post,createdDate:[2]]
==>[id:0,label:post,createdDate:[1]]
```

Comment: How to handle if a sort property don't exists.

Comment: one way would be to provide a `constant()` to `coalesce()`

Comment: Date filter don't work with Neptune graph. Appreciate help on this :

g.V().has('SalesAccount').order().by(coalesce(values('MarginDate'), constant('1900-01-01')),desc).

It gives error: {"requestId":"3a725f0f-b1b1-4473-a937-0e31648a023f","code":"UnsupportedOperationException"}

Comment: The answer is incomplete - it does not show the coalesce with a constant as needed by the original question.